# How to receive SNMP traps using net-snmp API?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

How can I receive traps using C or C++ and net-snmp module. I need sample code but the examples at http://www.net-snmp.org/ use syscalls but not API methods.

Comment: I am planning to develop an NMS Application in C/C++ in Qt environment that should send and receive snmpv2c traps using any snmp libraries. I have found some code that uses netsnmp API's for sending the traps, but could not able to find API's for receiving traps. please help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The net-snmp site **does** have comprehensive coding tutorials.

Look at http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Tutorials#Coding_Tutorials

**EDIT:**
Also see [source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/net_snmp/net_snmp-10/net-snmp/apps/snmptrapd.c) for snmptrapd as a guide for how to receive traps.

Comment: i have read about it and i only found a tool there that could handle SNMP traps which s the snmptrapd but the snmptrapd is just a tool..im looking for a library or function calls that could be used in listening for SNMP Traps in the UDP Port 162. There is a library n Net-SNMP that is for SNMP Traps sending..but for handling and decoding SNMP Traps i still didn't find one. Thanks.

Comment: Added a link to snmptrapd src.